# How to flatten a touchmove listener in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Trickshot #29](http://tutorialzine.com/books/jquery-trickshots/) shows how to define touch events in jQuery.  I've reworked it to my style of rogue writing in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/ynUHb/).

What the author does is define a touchmove listener whenever a touchstart event is fired.

```
request.dom.ball.on('mousedown touchstart',myTouchStart);
function myTouchStart(myEvent){
   request.dom.ball.on('mousemove.myNameSpace touchmove.myNameSpace',myTouchMove);
   function myTouchMove(myEvent) {
```

What I'd like to do is put myTouchMove outside of myTouchStart because my rogue style of JavaScript writing is to try to keep it as flat as possible, and not have functions inside of functions, if I can help it.

That might seem strange since I already wrap everything inside of:

```
(function() {
})();
```

to begin with, but I really don't want to have functions inside of functions inside of functions if I can help it.

Comment: You can define the function outside of the `touchstart` function. You'll just need to attach it inside of the function.

Comment: Thanks @kalley.  Is your idea the same as Ma3x?  Define myTouchMove as a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to return the inner function from another function (called a **closure**) that will pass any variables that you were originally referencing to your original function.

As far as I can tell in your case that's only one variable - `local` - but if you ever add new variables, just add a new argument to the function definition and the function call.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynUHb/1/

The affected code:

```
request.dom.ball.on('mousedown touchstart',myTouchStart);

function myTouchStart(myEvent){
    var local = {};
    //...
    request.dom.ball.on('mousemove.myNameSpace touchmove.myNameSpace',myTouchMove(local));
    //...
};

function myTouchMove(local) {
    return function(myEvent) {
        var myCss = {};

        myEvent = (myEvent.originalEvent.touches) ? myEvent.originalEvent.touches[0] : myEvent;
        myCss.top = local.elementPosition.y + myEvent.pageY - local.startPosition.y;
        request.dom.top.text(myCss.top);
        myCss.left = local.elementPosition.x + myEvent.pageX - local.startPosition.x;
        request.dom.left.text(myCss.left);
        request.dom.ball.css(myCss);
    };
};
```

**See:**

- [Forming Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clFrmC)

Comment: This works.  I can then rename "myCss" to "local" because my style is to put all variables local to the function inside a "local" variable.  That means that I need to rename myTouchMove(local) to something like myTouchMove(arg).

Comment: @Phillip: Possibly, but I would need to see the code to be sure. Just make sure that you rename the current variable with the name `local` to something different then, since that variable is being used inside the function now.

Comment: @Phillip: You are using the variable `myCss` to call `request.dom.ball.css(myCss);` so you shouldn't remove it. Maybe add it to `local.myCss = {}` and then replace all `myCss` with `local.myCss` if that's your style.